# Ajax call doesn't work after some time on mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, cordova, mobile

I'm writing a mobile app using cordova, angularjs and jquery.
I'm trying to get 2 files from the same directory.

- I do the first call straight after the page is loaded and it works.
- The  second call is done when the user presses a button. And it fails, it calls the '.error()' function.

The weird thing is that it works well on desktop.
I tried doing the call with vanila js, angularJS and jQueryand and still got the error on the second call.
I tried getting the same file, got the same result.
I tried calling straight after the first call and then things worked well, but that is not the function I want.
I used setTimeout(function() {}, 3000) and got the error again.

Any suggestions what can cause that?

Simplified version of my code:

```
angular.module('app.controllers.home',[])
.controller("HomeCtrl", function($scope, $location, $http) {
$scope.directory = 'files/';
$.ajax({
    url : $scope.directory + 'file.html',
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "html",
    success : function(data) {
        // that works
        var jData = $(data);
        jData.find('a.link').click(function(e){
            $scope.loadElem();
        });
        $('#panel').html(jData);
    },
    error : function(data) {
        alert('1st fail');
    }
});
setTimeout(function(){
    alert('second call');
    // that fails, goes to the .error
    $http.get($scope.directory + 'file.html').
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("2nd pass");
      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("2nd fail");
      }); }, 3000);

$scope.loadElem(){
    // that fails, goes to the .error
    $.ajax({
        url : $scope.directory + 'file.html',
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "html",
        success : function(data) {
            alert('3rd pass')
        },
        error : function(data) {
            alert('3rd fail');
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: please show us some code.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  Are you trying to load pages? ngRoute or the more powerful UI Router would be the way to handle that.  Or, are you trying to load partials into the same page?  ng-include would be the way to do that.  Without a better understanding of what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to give accurate advice.

Comment: I'm trying to load and transform a partial page. I did try the ng-include but I didn't like the functionality, after transforming the html it refused to put it in the view and didn't give me any error (I used $sce for putting the code in the view). I chose to use this set-up because it worked in using my browser and local server.

Comment: What does that mean: "transform the html"?

Comment: "transform the html" means adding and removing a certain elements from the html, also re-routing links and no I cannot do that in the html files, it needs to be done in the JS.

Comment: Well, if you're transforming the DOM, in AngularJS, you need to do that in a directive.  You shouldn't be doing that in a controller.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller.  If you would like to learn how to do this in AngularJS, then maybe you can change your question.  Ask how to properly load a partial and explain how you need to manipulate it, because any answer you get to your current question is going to result in propagating a pattern that is contrary to how you do things in AngularJS to ensure testability and maintainability.

Comment: I will try to make a directive in Angular and see if it will work. But I also want to know why is that ajax error happening.

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging, I come to the conclusion that I get this problem because I use angularJS routing and cordova.
Cordova puts all app files in 'file:///android_asset/www/' the first call takes that in consideration, maybe because it is part of the page initialization.
The second call doesn't, it is made from 'current_link/search_query' or 'file:///search_query', depending if there is '/' at the beginning of the link (*$http.get('item.html') or $http.get('/item.html')*).
So the fix is either:
the links are called like: 'file:///android_asset/www/' + 'path' + 'file',
or even better if there is a way to extract the current page path and get the first part in the page initialization.